# Put spotify in the system tray instead of taskbar

Tags: windows-8.1, spotify

Currently, spotify puts an icon *both* in the taskbar:

[image]

And the notification tray:

[image]

Normally I would just use something like Send2Tray, but I don't want two icons in the taskbar. Is there a way to put it only in the taskbar, like skype's option:

[image]

Comment: Right-click the Spotify icon in the notification area. Do you get a **Hide from Taskbar when closed** option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After doing some research, I found that if you check this box it fixes it:

[image]

Found it [here](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/How-can-I-hide-or-disable-the-tray-icon/m-p/55533#M10041)

Comment: Trick to this is you have to remember to "Close" the window instead of minimizing it. Minimizing still puts it in the taskbar. This also reveals one of the things I've always found annoying about Spotify to begin with. The "Close" button does not (and, as far as I can tell, cannot) behave like a normal "Close" button - you *must* use the tray icon to exit the application.