# Send spotify to tray after latest update

Tags: windows-8.1, spotify

Until the latest update to spotify (from what I can tell, `1.0.1.1060.gc75ebdfd`), spotify would [close to the system tray](https://superuser.com/questions/716129/put-spotify-in-the-system-tray-instead-of-taskbar).

However, the latest update causes closing spotify to actually close it, instead of sending it to the system tray. This wouldn't be too much of an issue, however it clutters my task bar and I like to keep it as clean as possible.

Is there a way to get it to close to the taskbar again, or at least minimize there?

I just tried installing an old version of spotify and it forced me to update, so that won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that's not what you wanna hear, but it seems they've disabled that feature [due to some community feedback](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Help-Desktop-Linux-Mac-and/Minimize-Spotify-in-system-tray-Windows-7-x64/m-p/1051761/highlight/true#M115711).

I am considering writing an **AutoHotKey** script to do that work for me. A good starting point is [this script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/MinimizeToTrayMenu.htm), that hides the active window to tray upon pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

**Result:**

[image: Minimized window]

Key points of the script:

```
; This is the hotkey used to hide the active window:
mwt_Hotkey = #h  ; Win+H

; This is the hotkey used to unhide the last hidden window:
mwt_UnHotkey = #u  ; Win+U

...

mwt_Minimize:
if mwt_WindowCount >= %mwt_MaxWindows%
{
    MsgBox No more than %mwt_MaxWindows% may be hidden simultaneously.
    return
}

(And onwards until "RestoreFromTrayMenu:")
```